# Is there a better way to recombine these congruences?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So I had seen this problem in which the solution breaks an equation of the form  $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ into $3$ congruences of the form

$$ a \equiv b \pmod{p_1} $$
$$ a \equiv b \pmod{p_2} $$
$$ a \equiv b \pmod{p_3} $$
where $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ are relatively prime and $n = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot p_3$.

I was wondering whether I could do this:

If $N = q_1 \cdot q_2 \cdot q_3$  , $\; q_1, q_2, q_3$ are relatively prime and

$$ c_1 \equiv d_1 \pmod{q_1} $$
$$ c_2 \equiv d_2 \pmod{q_2} $$
$$ c_3 \equiv d_3 \pmod{q_3} $$

then whether I could recombine these $3$ congruences into one congruence relation.

I tried writing each of the 3 linear congruences in the form that Bézout's identity provides. But the only relation I got was $(c_1 - d_1) \cdot (c_2 - d_2) \cdot (c_3 - d_3) \equiv 0  \pmod{ q_1 \cdot q_2 \cdot q_3}$.

Is there a way to get it into something like $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ form?

Comment: But it is already in this form; you have $b=0$ and 
$$a=(c_1 - d_1)(c_2 - d_2)(c_3 - d_3).$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\ p_1,p_2,p_3\ $ are pairwise (!) coprime, then with those numbers, the product $\ n=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3\ $ divides $\ a-b\ $ as well, giving $$a\equiv b\mod n$$ This is a consequence of the chinese remainder theorem.